# Using Anime.JS, how do I apply an animation to specific elements/paths of an svg?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, anime.js

I've written some code that rotates the entirety of the svg, but I don't know how to rotate the individual bodies.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <div class="content">

    <object id="demo-svg" data="./assets/test-graphic.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="100%" height="100%"></object>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animejs@3.0.1/lib/anime.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/css">

      body, html{ margin:0 } svg, g { transform-origin: unset unset; } path { transform-origin: 50% 50%; transform-box: fill-box; }

    </script>
  </div>

</head>

<div>

  <script>
    anime({
      targets: 'path',
      scale: [0.1, 1],
      opacity: [0.1, 1],
      rotate: "1turn",
      duration: 7000
    });
  </script>


</div>

</html>
```

The total svg code is much too large to paste in, so here's a snippet

```
<linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="69" y1="559.5" x2="1875" y2="559.5" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#22b226"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#2112b5"/>
```

for context, this gradient pairs to the path below.

```
<path d="M657,540a3,3,0,0,0-3,3v33a3,3,0,0,0,6,0V543A3,3,0,0,0,657,540Z" transform="translate(-69 -56)" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to target an individual part, target an individual part. Give them an ID or some other means of referring to them and go nuts.

```js
var tl = anime.timeline({
    duration: 700,
    easing: "easeOutElastic(1, 1)",
    endDelay: 400,
    loop: true
  })
  .add({
    targets: "svg",
    scale: [0, 1]
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".eye",
    scaleY: [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    easing: "easeInOutSine"
  });

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  tl.add({
    targets: ".pupil",
    translateX: anime.random(-12, 12),
    translateY: anime.random(-12, 12)
  });

tl.add({
  targets: "svg",
  scale: 0,
  easing: "easeInElastic(1, 1)",
  endDelay: 1000
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100vmin" height="100vmin" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
  <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="40" stroke-width="6" stroke="#1F1F1F" fill="#AF87CC" transform-origin="60 60" />
  <g class="eye" transform-origin="60 60">
    <circle class="pupil" cx="60" cy="60" r="24" />
    <circle cx="77" cy="43" r="10" fill="#FFFFFF" />
  </g>
</svg>
```